# Objective C - CCCallFuncND correct passing of an argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been trying to call the function below.It seems that whenever in the function *playNote* I'm trying to access the object that I'm passing as the argument (myNum) it always crashes. I'm very new and I probably don't understand how to pass parameters through CCCallFuncND. All comments are appreciated.

This is the call that passes the argument *myNum*:

```
id action2 = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playNote:data:) data:(NSNumber *)myNum];
```

This is the whole block:

```
- (void)muteAndPlayNote:(NSInteger)noteValue :(CCLayer*)currentLayer
{
myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:noteValue];

NSLog(@"Test the number: %d", [myNum integerValue]);

id action1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(muteAudioInput)];

id action2 = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playNote:data:) data:(NSNumber *)myNum];

id action3 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3];

id action4 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(unmuteAudioInput)];

[currentLayer runAction: [CCSequence actions:action1, action2, action3, action4, nil]];

}
```

NSLog never displays anything it crashes at this line.

```
- (void) playNote:(id)sender data:(NSNumber *)MIDInoteValue

{
NSLog(@"Test number 2: %d", [MIDInoteValue integerValue]);
int myInt = [MIDInoteValue floatValue];
[PdBase sendFloat: 55 toReceiver:@"midinote"];
[PdBase sendBangToReceiver:@"trigger"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is:

```
-(void)playNote:(id)sender data:(NSNumber*)MIDInoteValue
```

but it should be:

```
-(void)playNote:(id)sender data:(void*)data
```

This is defined in the CCActionInstant.h as:

```
typedef void (*CC_CALLBACK_ND)(id, SEL, id, void *);
```

Also I'm pretty sure you get some information from the crash, like the call stack end the console output, would be helpful to paste it here in case I'm wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

Note that CCCallFunc* actions are inherently unsafe if you're using ARC.

Regardless of that it's generally better to use CCCallBlock* actions (which are safe to use under ARC) because then you often don't even need to pass in data as parameters, you can just use the variables of the local scope inside the block:

```
myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:noteValue];
[CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    NSInteger myInt = [myNum integerValue];
    // do something with myInt, or just use noteValue directly
}];
```

PS: check your code for data type consistency. You create NSNumber `myNum` as an `NSInteger` value, later you get it via the `floatValue` method which implicitly converts the number to `float` and then back to `int` (use `integerValue` instead). You assign it to an `int` value which is the same as int only on 32 bit systems, on 64 bit systems like iPhone 5S NSInteger is actually a 64 bit type (use `NSInteger` instead of `int`).

You can get nasty value conversion issues (as well as issues when building for 64 bit devices) if you aren't consistent in using the exact same data type. Plus you're possibly even getting warnings about this already - take those warnings seriously.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, knowing this will save me headache down the line

Answer (score 1):

For those encountering problems with this function, here are the working versions:

```
id action2 = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playNote:data:) data:(void *)noteValue];
```

and then the definition:

```
- (void) playNote:(id)sender data:(void *)midiNoteCode

{
int myNum = midiNoteCode; //void * to int conversion may cause problems on 64bit platform, wrap it into NSInteger
[PdBase sendFloat: (float)myNum toReceiver:@"midinote"];
[PdBase sendBangToReceiver:@"trigger"];
```

}